# USPS May have lost my tax return. Cannot check status?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040, mailing

Unlike other 200 IQ folks, I just mailed my tax return in an envelope with a stamp.  So I have no registered mail or tracking.  I mailed it on March 22, it's May 10, 7 weeks later, and still no sign.  I've tried both the IRS automated hotline as well as the online tool and input my information but it says no information is available in both cases.

1. Is there any way to verify the IRS has received the return apart from the website and hotline?  Or does this mean they have indeed not received my return?
2. Several points on the IRS website urge me not to resend my forms.  (This seems very puzzling to me)
3. If I do not resend my forms before the May 17 deadline, will I be penalized anyway?

Should I resend forms (this time with registered mail) or just hope for the best?

Comment: FWIW I sent mine certified with tracking before 4/15 and it shows they were delivered shortly after but the IRS site still doesn't show a refund status for me. I wouldn't worry too much, odds are they made it. Are you getting a refund or do you owe? Especially if you expect a refund, I don't think filing late is an issue... if you owe, there might be some extra interest or penalties I suppose, but I doubt they'd be really serious. IANAL

Comment: How did you deliver your envelope to USPS? By that I mean, did you hand it to your postal carrier at your residence, or leave it unattended at your residence (in/on mailbox, e.g.) for the postal carrier to pick up, or drop it into a blue curbside postal box on the street or outside the post office, or drop it into a slot inside the post office, or hand it to a post office employee inside the post office? I ask because theft of mail from the blue postal boxes is rampant in my area, to the point where people have taken crowbars and pried them open.

Comment: I efiled my return April 18. Saw my small refund direct deposited on May 5th, and set to receive my Stimulus Deposit May 12th. Not an answer, of course, but I'd never mail paper if I didn't have to. And then, I send it registered mail.

Comment: Registered is unnecessary, because tax returns should cost almost nothing to replace. _Certified_ gets you proofs of mailing and delivery much cheaper. (And since you hand it in at the counter, you avoid any box-theft issue :-) (@JTP)

Comment: Yes, certified. Thanks for the correction. It's a proof of delivery.

Comment: The mail lady comes and picks up mail out of our doorslots.  I heard her come and retrieve it, so I know the USPS got it.  I am receiving a refund and do not owe.

I am still nervous _not_ to file on time.  I guess my fear is what could go wrong if they receive a second copy of my return?